# mock function with interface passes when it should fail

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

How to mock this:

```
interface Animal {
   walk(how): Promise<string>
}
```

```
class Main {
   public static async beAlive(creature: Animal) {
       try {
           return await creature.walk();
       } catch (e) {
         throw new Error('cant walk');
       }
```

Now the test, I want mock this interface:

```
it("should walk", () => {
const animal = {
    walk: jest.fn(async(who) => {
        return await Promise.reject('cant walk')
});

await expect(Main.beAlive(animal)).rejects.toThrow();
```

But it passes. Why ?

Comment: `But it passes`, so what is your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the mock:

```
const animal = {
    walk: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue('cant walk')
}
```